# change the color of field based on a value crm 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a Date of Birth field and an age field in a CRM Form. When the record is saved the age is calculated and if the age is less than 18 the Age field should turn red.

When I save the form the field turns red for a second and then changes back to normal. My web resource is using OnSave event of the form. When I use the change color code on ONChange event of the Age field, I have to save the form twice to show that it turns red.

How do I get rid of this saving the form twice? Here is my code:

```
function setAge() 
{
    var DOB = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_dob").getValue();
    var Today = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_bookingdate").getValue();
    Today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var db = 0;
    if(DOB > Today )
    {
        alert("Please Enter Genuine BirthDate !!!");
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_dob").setValue(null);
    }
    else
    {
        db = Today.getFullYear() - DOB.getFullYear();
        var x = Today.getDate() ;
        var y = DOB.getDate() ;
        var a = Today.getMonth() + 1;
        var b = DOB.getMonth() + 1;
        if((a < b) || (a==b & x < y))
            db=db - 1;
        }
        var result = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_age").setValue(db);
        if (db <18)
        {
            document.getElementById("inmate_age").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            document.getElementById("inmate_age_c").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use the last IF condition separately on ONChange event of Age field. This prompts me to save the record twice.

Comment: Might find [jquery watch plugin](https://github.com/darcyclarke/jQuery-Watch-Plugin) useful; it should allow you to watch where your background color is changing. Will of course require jquery

Comment: I exactly know when it is changing.

Comment: when is that? could post more code..

Comment: I have posted all the code. So if I use the above code on OnSave event of the form, the field turns red and then back to normal. If I use the

Comment: The field changes to red when I save the form and then back to normal again. If I use this 
`if (db <18)
        {
            document.getElementById("inmate_age").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            document.getElementById("inmate_age_c").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }` 
in a separate function and call that function OnChange event of the field, I have to save the form twice to turn the field red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not calculate the field onChange?

e.g.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('inmate_age').addOnChange(function() {
    var theyAre18 = yourFunctionToCalculateIfTheyAre18OrNot();
    if (theyAre18) {
        //make the background white
    }
    else {
        //make the background red
    }
});
```

That way you could run it once onload and only change if the value changes. When you change the colour onSave, the form is going to reload anyway and your changes will be lost.

Comment: I am calculating the field onSave not onChange. I have to calculate the Age onSave as Date of birth need to be entered first.

Comment: OnChange fires AFTER the user entered the value. So just apply it to onChange of the DOB field. Doing it onSave will not persist the colour of the field because the form immediately reloads.

Comment: Thank you, such an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your specific error is related to the fact that after the save, the form is refreshed, losing the color that you set. You need to calculate it on the onLoad too.

```
Basically what happened is:
OnSave -> Calculate
Form refresh -> Lose the color
OnLoad -> you need to re-apply your script
```